# What does $FlowExpectedError do?

Tags: javascript, types, flowtype

What does `$FlowExpectedError` do? I see it sometimes in code annotated with Flow but I couldn't find any official documentation about that annotation on flow.org.

Example:

```
// $FlowExpectedError
const foo: string = 1;
```

Comment: I dont know about flow, but this will give an error in JS `Missing initializer in const declaration`. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Errors/Missing_initializer_in_const

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Usually it's a value of [suppress_comment](https://flow.org/en/docs/config/options/#toc-suppress-comment-regex) option, in `.flowconfig` file. The meaning is:

> Defines a magical comment that suppresses any Flow errors on the following line.

So, this comment says flow to silently ignore the error on the following line.